# Release management email notification not sending

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

No email notification is sending from my RM system on releases.

Following things has been done:

1. Smtp setting has been updated in the system
2. Enabled approver notification in 'Acceptance step' and 'validation step'.
3. Email id is updated and 'Receive email notification' is 'Yes' for the approver and validator. The user are release managers.

Did I missed anything? Why emails are not sending?

Comment: Did you change your rm server settings sometime recently, or migrated the server? Can you share the server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks right. [Enable the logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/13/how-to-enable-detailed-logs-and-collect-traces-from-various-release-management-components.aspx) on the server side to see if any errors are thrown.

I would double check the SMTP settings. Username/password are obvious possible mistake, but depending on your SMTP requirement, you might need to specified a valid email address from your domain as the sender address.

Comment: Verified the smtp settings.

Comment: Tracing is enabled in the RM agent & server, but i could't find any log file in file path specified in the config file...!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer Joerage. SMTP setting was not working in the TFS server...!

I faced one more issue with the notification mail. View request link was opening old url of release management site...! Earlier I upgraded the RM server and client, after that changed the url also.

Again I lost couple of minutes to find out the problem.

The url is configure in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\services\web.config" file under setting "ApprovalRequestEmailLanding". I changed the value to correct url and it's working...! This could be a bug in the release management system.

May be this will be helpful for someone.